# get Max method for DateTime type

Tags: vb.net, datetime, reflection

I am looking for an `Enumerable.Max` method that returns a `DateTime`, but it seems this method does not exist.

I tried using reflection to find it, but none of the results returned a `DateTime`:

```
Dim test = GetType(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static).
    Where(Function(m) m.Name = "Max")
```

Is there such a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enumerable` has no `Max` method specified for `DateTime` type, but it has generic `Max(IEnumerable<TSource>)` method that can process objects of classes that implements `IComparable<T>` or `IComparable` interfaces, including `DateTime`.

So you can use this method:

```
class Program
{
    delegate DateTime MaxDelegate(IEnumerable<DateTime> values);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MaxDelegate d = Enumerable.Max<DateTime>;
        var values = new DateTime[] { DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.Now, DateTime.MaxValue };
        var result = d(values);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```